# Remove SecondaryOwner from site collection with powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell

Does anyone know how to remove the secondary owner of a site collection with the help of powershell?

I know how to set the SecondaryOwnerAlias with the help of powershell but so far I did not find any possibility to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `SecondaryContact` of `SPSite` object.

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://sp2010:90"
$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
$site.SecondaryContact = $null;
```

**EDIT**

Just ran the updated code above on my SP 2010 VM and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
Get-SPSite "http://sitename/sites/teams/*" | Set-SPSite –SecondaryOwner $null
```

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958.aspx)

Comment: -SecondaryOwner is not listed as valid parameter on the source you give.
And it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-SecondaryContact` instead of `-SecondaryOwner`.